# App update/install claim insufficient storage with 3GB free on SD

Tags: installation, insufficient-memory, storage

[image: default write disk]
[image: insufficient storage notification]

As you can see, the default write disk is set to the SD card with more than 3GB free, but it still complains of insufficient storage even for apps that do not exceed 100MB total size (I did not check the minimum size to trigger it, however).

What can I do to get around it?

Comment: Have you already checked with our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info)? If so, you had learned that the error has nothing to do at all with your SD card, and could even happen with 1TB free there. Regardless of the install location, the app first will be downloaded to a temporary place on your internal storage – which is where the space is obviously lacking. Hints for what to do can be found in the mentioned tag-wiki as well.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you try to update and app, it first gets moved automatically to phone memory, even if the preferred install location is set to sd card.

Now, it is quite possible  (like in my case), the phone memory does not have sufficient storage for the app, or to hold the update along with the previous version. In that case, the apps will not get updated.

Whenever any app that was on the sd card is updated, you must again manually transfer it back to external storage, or it'll remain in phone memory